# Pandas: Aggregate mean ("totals") for each combination of dimensions

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a table like this:

| gender | city | age | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | newyork | 10_20y | 2010 | 10.5 |
| female | newyork | 10_20y | 2010 | 11 |

I'd like to add all possible means for combinations of dimensions 1-3 to the **same table** (or a new dataframe that I can concatenate with the original).

The time dimension should not be aggregated. Example of means added for different combinations:

| gender | city | age | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **total** | **total** | **total** | 2010 | (mean) |
| male | **total** | **total** | 2010 | (mean) |
| male | newyork | **total** | 2010 | (mean) |
| female | **total** | **total** | 2010 | (mean) |
| female | newyork | **total** | 2010 | (mean) |
| ... **total** | ... **total** | 10_20y | 2010 | (mean) |

Comment: To get quicker response you can add reproducible dummy dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using groupby on multiple columns will groupby with all combinations of these columns. So a simple `df.groupby(["city", "age"]).mean()` will achieve the mean for the "total", "city", "age" combination. The problem here is you want all combinations of all size for the list `["gender", "city", "age"]`. It's not straightforward and I think a more pythonic way can be found but here is my proposal :

```py
## create artificial data
cols = ["gender", "city", "age"]
genders = ["male", "female"]
cities = ["newyork", "losangeles", "chicago"]
ages = ["10_20y", "20_30y"]
n = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"gender" : np.random.choice(genders, n),
                   "city" : np.random.choice(cities, n),
                   "age" : np.random.choice(ages, n),
                   "value": np.random.randint(1, 20, n)})

## the dataframe we will append during the process
new = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

## itertools contains the function combinations
import itertools

## list all size combinations possible
for n in range(0, len(cols)+1):
    for i in itertools.combinations(cols, n):

        ## if n > 0, the combinations is not empty, 
        ## so we can directly groupby this sublist and take the mean
        if n != 0:
            agg_df = df.groupby(list(i)).mean().reset_index() 
            ## reset index since for multiple columns, the result will be multiindex

        ## if n=0, we just want to take the mean of the whole dataframe
        else:
            agg_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
            agg_df.loc[0, "value"] = df.loc[:, "value"].mean() 
            ## a bit ugly since this mean is an integer not a dataframe

        ## from here agg_df will have n+1 columns, 
        ## for instance for ["gender"] we will have only "gender" and "value" columns
        ## "city" and "age" are missing since we aggregate on it
        for j in cols:
            if j not in i:
                agg_df.loc[:, j] = "total" ## adding total as you asked for
        new = new.append(agg_df)
```

For instance, I find :

```
new
   gender        city     age      value
0   total       total   total   9.750000
0  female       total   total   8.083333
1    male       total   total  12.250000
0   total     chicago   total   8.000000
1   total  losangeles   total  11.428571
2   total     newyork   total  11.666667
0   total       total  10_20y   8.100000
1   total       total  20_30y  11.400000
0  female     chicago   total   7.333333
1  female  losangeles   total   9.250000
2  female     newyork   total   8.000000
3    male     chicago   total   9.000000
4    male  losangeles   total  14.333333
5    male     newyork   total  19.000000
0  female       total  10_20y   7.333333
1  female       total  20_30y   8.833333
2    male       total  10_20y   9.250000
3    male       total  20_30y  15.250000
0   total     chicago  10_20y   7.285714
1   total     chicago  20_30y   9.666667
2   total  losangeles  10_20y  10.000000
3   total  losangeles  20_30y  12.500000
4   total     newyork  20_30y  11.666667
0  female     chicago  10_20y   7.250000
1  female     chicago  20_30y   7.500000
2  female  losangeles  10_20y   7.500000
3  female  losangeles  20_30y  11.000000
4  female     newyork  20_30y   8.000000
5    male     chicago  10_20y   7.333333
6    male     chicago  20_30y  14.000000
7    male  losangeles  10_20y  15.000000
8    male  losangeles  20_30y  14.000000
9    male     newyork  20_30y  19.000000
```

It's a base work, I think you can work around